# TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory

Tags: solidity, remix

I was using remix for basic solidity. Can someone explain if I'm using string.concat() why is it giving that error even if both types are string.
I tried the [Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html?highlight=string#the-functions-bytes-concat-and-string-concat)  as well but it gives the same error.

from solidity:
TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract test{
    function hi(string memory name) pure public returns(string memory){
        string memory greetings = string.concat("Hello", name);
        return greetings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string.concat` function was 'fixed' to take and return strings in [solidity v0.8.12](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#0812-2022-02-16), so you should change the `pragma solidity ^0.8.0` to `pragma solidity ^0.8.12`, for example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract test {
    function hi(string memory name) pure public returns(string memory){
        string memory greetings = string.concat("Hello", name);
        return greetings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for letting know.